# $(this) is not working in my jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When click my function, i want to change a parent that have this function element. But $(this) not working.

What is wrong?

```
function accountConfirm(message, title, yes_label, no_label, callback) {
    console.log($(this));
    $("#accountConfirmModal").attr('data-confirm-yes', false);
    if ($("#accountConfirm").length == 0) {
        .....
    }

    $("#accountConfirmModal .content p").html(message || "");
};
```

That is the HTML element

```
<button type="button" id="deleteScrollTop" class="btn btn-delete"
                                        onclick="accountConfirm(jsResources.addressDeleteQuestion,jsResources.addressDeleteTitle, jsResources.yes,jsResources.no ,function(res){
                                            if(res){
                                                window.location.href = '@(Url.RouteUrl("CustomerAddressDelete", new {addressId = address.Id}))'
                                            }
                                        })">
                                    <img src="@Url.ThemeFolderUrl("_images/delete.png")" alt="delete address" />
                                </button>
```

Comment: _"What is wrong?"_ - the way you are attaching the event handler to the element in the first place, using "old-school" HTML attributes. You should do this using jQuery's `.on()`

Comment: When you say not working, what do you mean. Error? Or something unexpected. You will have to add those details

Comment: @CBroe - I tend to use `.click()`; is it now deprecated?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan it is deprecated as a shortcut for .on from jQuery 3 on.

Comment: @CBroe good to know, been a while I'd looked at the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke a function in a `onclick` attribute, it is actually invoked by the window object, so `this` will become the window object itself, not the button.

If you want the `this` become the button itself, you will have to use `apply` method of the function.

For example:

```
function somefunc(arg1, arg2){
    console.log("This is ", this);
    console.log("Arg1: ", arg1);
    console.log("Arg2: ", arg2);
}
```

In `onclick`

```
<button onclick="somefunc.apply(this, [1, 2])">Button</button>
```

Comment: its working when i add 'this' like a variable that what u saying. thankyu so much for explanation its was so beneficial

Answer (score 4):

You possibly meant to do this

Always a good idea to consolidate on jQuery if you use it and not use inline event handlers

Assuming the button ID is unique

```js
function accountConfirm(message, title, yes_label, no_label, callback) {
  $("#accountConfirmModal").attr('data-confirm-yes', false);
  if ($("#accountConfirm").length == 0) {
    .....
  }

  $("#accountConfirmModal .content p").html(message || "");
};

const route = function(res) {
  if (res) {
    window.location.href = '@(Url.RouteUrl("CustomerAddressDelete", new {addressId = address.Id}))'
  }
}
$("#deleteScrollTop").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this));
  accountConfirm(jsResources.addressDeleteQuestion,
    jsResources.addressDeleteTitle,
    jsResources.yes,
    jsResources.no, route)
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="deleteScrollTop" class="btn btn-delete">
  <img src="@Url.ThemeFolderUrl("_images/delete.png")" alt="delete address" />
</button>
```

Comment: I need the $(this) in my function. But i got it, thankyu for answer

Comment: You can pass it in my call too `accountConfirm(this,jsResources.addressDeleteQuestion,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access "this" in an onClick-event, you do it like this:

```
<button onclick="accountConfirm(this)">
  your button
</button>

<script>
  function accountConfirm(elmnt) {
    console.log("this: ", elmnt);
   
  };
</script>
```